# Update Jekyll project local

Tags: jekyll, bundler

I try to update my local Jekyll version in my projects.

First i run `gem update jekyll` in iTerm to update Jekyll. This works.

But how do I update the version in my project? Is there any command for the command line or should I change the new version only in my gemfile? When I run `bundle update jekyll` it only updates the dependencies in my gemfile.lock but not to the new jekyll version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gemfile already contains the needed information for how to behave when performing an update. Your gems can include version numbers.

> The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 2.0.3 is identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1. ~> 2.1 is identical to >= 2.1 and < 3.0. ~> 2.2.beta will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.

So every time you update it will do a [conservative update](http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-install.1.html#CONSERVATIVE-UPDATING) following the above criteria. If you want another version, then you should edit it manually in `Gemfile`.